# Map, filter and itertools for composing asynchronous iterators

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio, python-itertools

Does Python support functional-style operations on asynchronous iterators? I know that I can use `map`, `filter` and `itertools` to lazily transform and consume data coming from normal generators:

```
from itertools import accumulate, takewhile

def generator():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

# create another iterator, no computation is started yet:
another_iterator = takewhile(lambda x: x < 100, accumulate(generator()))
# start consuming data:
print(list(another_iterator))
# [1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33, 54, 88]
```

Now, the same thing is not supported on Python 3.6's asynchronous generators/iterators because of course they do not implement the normal iterator protocol:

```
async def agenerator():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

accumulate(agenerator())
```

> TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Is there some kind of async map or async itertools to achieve the similarly lazy behaviour in Python 3.6/3.7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most full asynchronous version of itertools I saw is [aiostream](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. Your example will be:

```
import asyncio
from aiostream.stream import takewhile, accumulate, list as alist


async def agenerator():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


async def main():
    another_iterator = takewhile(
        accumulate(agenerator()),
        lambda x: x < 100, 
    )

    res = await alist(another_iterator)

    print(res)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting, especially the async version of `list`. I'm looking into the library, it seems fairly mature although it's at 0.3.0.